# local modules node.js :can't load files other than index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I am trying to learn local module setup in my express js application.

`test-module` folder is created in my project folder and it contains two files

1)index.js

```
 module.exports = {

      indexfunc:function(){
       console.log('ok from index');
     }


  }
```

2)hello.js.

```
 module.exports = {

  helloFunc:function(){
     console.log('ok from hello');
  }

}
```

importing this module in `app.js` file

```
   var mymodule = require('hello-module');
    console.log(mymodule);

   output:{ indexfunc: [Function: indexfunc] }
```

But this returns `console.log(require('hello-module').hello)` `undefined`.

package.json for this module

```
{
  "name": "hello-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hello` is a file in `hello-module`, you need to pass it as the `path` to `require`. Do:

```
console.log(require('hello-module/hello'))
```

By doing :

```
console.log(require('hello-module').hello)
```

You are printing the `hello` property exported by `index.js`

Comment: Do you have an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022577/node-js-local-modules-module-not-found-error-in-subfolder

Answer (score 1):

I addition to @Ayush answer, if your goal is to execute code from other files in a module folder you can export a reference like so :

```
//index.js

const helloModule = require('./hello');

module.exports = {
      hello: helloModule,
      indexfunc:function(){
       console.log('ok from index');
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022577/node-js-local-modules-module-not-found-error-in-subfolder