# node.js local modules: module not found error in subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

Here is the folder structure of my application

[image: Here is the folder structure of my application]

I am refering `app_modules/bar` and `app_modules/foo`  as local modules

**package.json** Root folder

```
 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "foo": "file:app_modules/foo",
    "bar": "file:app_modules/bar",
    "hello": "file:hello"
  }
```

when i require the modules as

`var fooModule = require('app_modules/foo');` i got module not found error

`package.json` for `foo` module

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: do the `foo` and `bar` folders contains an `index.js` file or a `package.json`?

Comment: it contains both files

Answer (score 1):

By default, `require` looks for modules inside the `node_modules` folder. To include modules from a custom locations, you need to prefix the path with `./` or `../` depending the level the module is from the file from where you require it.

So, If you want to require `app_modules/foo` from `app.js`, you will have to do:

```
var fooModule = require('./app_modules/foo');
```

Comment: but i have pointed that in the `node_modules` folder check my `package.json`

Comment: try `require('foo')`